# Unusual logcat message shown infinitely - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

I'm developing an app with ActionBar Sherlock, HoloEverywhere libraries. I have been coding all the while, forgetting to check logcat console for a while.

My app runs fine, but I see this unusual logcat error message that keeps flowing in as an infinite loop.

```
09-11 00:05:33.225: D/TileRenderer(25688): glEndTilingQCOM: 0x502
```

with a tag `TileRenderer` I have checked through out my workspace, there is no indications of a word `TileRenderer` in the code.

Please can some one help me on what is causing this message? I'm afraid of any memory exceptions because of this....

Comment: That's a debug message and does not necessarily mean something bad. Probably a vendor modification specific to Qualcomm GFX. I can't find any mention of "TileRenderer" in the whole ICS Android source.

Comment: @zapl you are right. That debug message comes on my HTC One V and not on simulators. Thanks for the info... I got paranoid.

Comment: I m getting the same message at my Sony Xperia S phone. But I have been using this phone from April 2012 for active development (I use it at work roughly 8 hours per day!) And just started to notice it in my current project...

Comment: I too get the same error debug message on my Xperia SL that I use for development. I notice that message whenever any animation is happening in the device

Comment: This may be showing up because of the regular refresh being caused by the renderer. Similarly continous messages show up when displaying active webpages on webview because they have to be refereshed again and again due to changing content.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a game running in the background, it might be trying to update things. The logcat reads everything on the phone. Try setting the logcat to only read that app, then if it still pops up, you have a problem. Otherwise, you're fine.

Comment: While it would be interesting to know if the message is from the app under development, the more important point is that it does not necessarily indicate a problem.